# Could not load the 'chef-solo' provisioner from the load path

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I have freshly installed ChefDK on my workstation, downloaded the starter kit and modified .kitchen.yml to follows:

```
---
driver:
  name: opennebula
  opennebula_endpoint: http://10.1.1.1/zonea
  oneauth_file: /home/local/.one/one_auth
  template_name: CHEF-TESTVM
  vm_hostname: CHEF-TESTVM-FRONT-END
  public_key_path: /home/local/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  username: root
  memory: 4096
  require_chef_omnibus: false
  user_variables:
    FILEHOME: http://10.1.1.2/~dev/repo/

provisioner:
  name: chef-solo
  environments_path: /home/local/chef-repo/cookbooks/init/environments/
  role_path: /home/local/chef-repo/cookbooks/init/roles/

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-12.04

suites:
  - name: default
    provisioner:
      solo_rb:
        environment: dev
    run_list:
      - recipe[wfe]
      - role[common]
    attributes:
```

Kitchen is provided with the Chef. (use the built-in kitchen/gem/bundle etc)

And I ran `kitchen test` it gives the following message:

```
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ClientError
>>>>>> Message: Could not load the 'chef-solo' provisioner from the load path. Please ensure that your provisioner is installed as a gem or included in your Gemfile if using Bundler.
>>>>>> ----------------------
```

`which chef-solo` returns `/opt/chefdk/bin/chef-solo`

If I change `chef-solo` to `chef-zero`, it is omitting the same error during a `kitchen diagnose`:

```
exception: "#<Kitchen::ClientError: Could not load the 'chef-zero' provisioner
  from the load path. Please ensure that your provisioner is installed as a gem
  or included in your Gemfile if using Bundler.>"
```

I have already installed kitchen-opennebula gem, but I suspect this problem is nothing related to that.

What is going on?

Comment: try `chef-zero` rather then `chef-solo` as a provisioner, and report back. please also update your question and state whether are you using `kitchen` as a part of `chefdk` or not.

Comment: @MrRoth Hi I am using the Kitchen that shipped with ChefDK. Also I tried to use chef-zero instead, it is omitting the same type of error (load error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was a typo:

`chef-solo` should be `chef_solo` in the yml.

Solved.

I had another similar problem that blocked me some time try to find out why (`data_bag_path` vs `data_bags_path`, it should have an 's')